# How to standardize the text function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`=text(5/7/19,[Windows date format])` depends on the computer you are opening the Excel file from. For instance: `=text(5/7/19, "mm/dd/yy")` works on the company computer because that's how the windows formatted the date, but in my computer, it has to be `=text(5/7/19, "dd/mm/yy")` else it will return a different value and using other functions such as `=datevalue(text(5/7/19, "mm/dd/yy")` will return a `#VALUE!` error on my home computer. This is not good because it is very variable when the file is being moved around computers. How to standardize this?

Answer (score 1):

So what about:

```
=TEXT(43592,"mm")&"/"&TEXT(43592,"dd")&"/"&TEXT(43592,"yy")
```

Or reference a cell where you have put your date.

Comment: What I have in my formula was `=text([@Date],"mm/dd/yy")` which is a table reference. But still errors. I'll try out this formula though

Comment: `=TEXT([@Datum],"mm")&"/"&TEXT([@Datum],"dd")&"/"&TEXT([@Datum],"yy")` will work

Comment: The output of this returns a `#VALUE!` error still for my `datevalue()` still though. But if I do it `=TEXT([@Datum],"dd")&"/"&TEXT([@Datum],"mm")&"/"&TEXT([@Datum],"yy")` it will work. So I guess even in this form, the order still matters

Comment: @Pherdindy yes that definitely matters! But why do you need Datevalue at all when you have access to the original date? A true date is nothing more than a numerical value in excel. My answer just shows how to format the date both on your PC, and business in the same way

Comment: You might be right about my code being redundant. I don't remember why I ended up doing that, but maybe I encountered a problem. Will try removing that portion. But then it's still an interesting thing to note that the `=text()` function varies depending on the computer which can make things broken when another person opens on another computer

Comment: I think I used `datevalue` to isolate the day because I had entries such as `4pm 4/7/19` and when I converted that cell to a number, it wil be something like 47690.6 where the decimal represents the time. But my calculations needed it by day so I used `datevalue(text([@Column,"mm/dd/yy"))` to just get the whole number portion of the day.

Comment: @Pherdindy you can use 'INT' function to get the whole number and maintain the true date value that way

Comment: Thanks yeah that is a simpler way for sure and probably error proof

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think it is possible - see the [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-datevalue-function-d17c72f0-8829-482f-a334-14c4f124876e)

**Quote:**

> **Problem:** The value in the date_text argument is not in sync with the system’s date and time settings*
>
> If your system date and time settings follow the mm/dd/yyyy format,
>   then a formula such as =DATEVALUE(“22/6/2000”) will result in a #VALUE! error. But the same formula will display the correct value when the system's date and time is set to dd/mm/yyyy format.
>
> **Solution:** Make sure that your system’s date and time settings (both Short time and Long time) matches the date format in the
>   date_text argument.

I think the only solution is to make sure that your date is in the valid (i.e. recognised by the system) date format before any other function (like DATEVALUE) is applied.

It will be easy to achieve if your function is simply `=text(5/7/19,[Windows date format])`. You can reference your cell field (e.g. `=[@Date]`) and format a given cell using an "universal" date format (the ones that start with * sign).

[image]

However, if you are combining `=text(5/7/19,[Windows date format])` with some other formula (e.g. when you want to display a full sentence like `A very important event happened on 5/7/19`) then, unfortunately, cell format won't save you here and we're out of solutions. In such case the end user would need to manually modify the date cell in order to make it recognisable.

Comment: Thanks I guess it's possible with conditional statements if it returns a `#VALUE!` error it can use another date string instead but I haven't tried yet. But was looking for a more basic approach if there was or maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: That's a good idea, or you can have some helper table with dates in a few different formats (and only return the one that doesn't return #VALUE or is recognised as a date). And no, you are doing nothing wrong :) as far as I know there is no "easy" or "standard" solution to that issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks since JvdV pointed out that my code may be redundant I might take a look at it first. But it was still interesting to find my workbook with broken cell values when transferred around